# Add new system call at FreeBSD

Tags: makefile, system-calls, freebsd

I wanna add custom helloworld syscall to FreeBSD. I used following link as my guide: http://members.tripod.com/s_mathur/bsdhowto.html In step 4 says: Modify the Make File to include sys_hello.c , etc and recompile the kernel! Which Make File? Where is it? and how to compile it and how call syscall hello?

The error that I faced with it, is:
init_sysent.o:(.data + 0x6638): undefined reference to 'sys_hello'

I think that it is because of my Make file, because I don't know I should modify which Make File.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you are not ready to do any kernel development and as such strongly suggest you refrain from it.

I don't know how you ended up on that guide, I have trouble finding it when I look for ways to add system calls to the FreeBSD kernel.

The guide has bits which are outdated and some which were always wrong.

You created a new file (sys_hello.c) but did not add it to the build process. Figuring out how to do that should be trivial.
1. pick a syscall which is always provided, like fork
2. find the file implementing it
3. grep the source tree for mentions of that file
4. profit

Performing the steps and getting the answer is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
int syshello(p, uap)
struct proc* p; struct syshello_args uap;
```

K&R C declaration? Just how old is this?
The first argument for several years now is struct thread *.

```
{
sprintf(uap->buf,"Hello"); /* fill the buffer with Hello */
```

Fundamentally wrong. Consider what happens if userspace passes a kernel address. Also this assumes shared address spaces to "work". The code should have used copyout. Except the code is additionally wrong by not having an argument allowing the userspace to say what the size is.

```
p->p_retval[0] = 0; /* set the return value of the system call*/
return 0;
}
```

As noted earlier, given your difficulty with figuring out what to do with the new file it is clear you are new to programming and as such you really should not touch the kernel until you grow.